# How can I access the metadata of a SharePoint page from another?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

How can I access the metadata of one SharePoint page from another? Through a Web Part? I don't want to use any type of list.

I had a look at [this blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2012/07/27/using-dreamweaver-and-design-manager-with-sharepoint-2013.aspx), but I still can't seem to figure it out.

Is the following code relevant?

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
    <PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField id="PageContent" FieldName="PublishingPageContent" DisableInputFieldLabel="true" runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Please format your question to be *at least* readable.

Comment: Please read the question now.

Answer (score 0):

Don't store the shared information in a page, it is a better to store Metadata in PropertyBag.

You have different Scope for storing properties:

- Farm
- List item
- Web application
- Site
- List/Library Folder.

Example from: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43601/SharePoint-Property-Bag

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
        try
        {
            using (SPSite RootSite = new SPSite(URL))
            {
                using (SPWeb SiteCollection = RootSite.OpenWeb())
                {                    
                    try
                    {
                        SiteCollection.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                       // Get connection string from Property bag
                        if (SiteCollection.AllProperties.ContainsKey("ConnectionString"))
                        {
                            ConnectionString = SiteCollection.AllProperties["ConnectionString"].ToString();
                        }                        
                        // Set siteID in the Property bag
                        SiteCollection.Properties["siteID"] = siteID;
                        SiteCollection.Properties.Update();
                        SiteCollection.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;                        
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) 
                    { 
                      //Handle Exception  
                    }           
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)        
        {            
        }
        });
```